# Splitting window in Vim

Tags: vim, split

When doing a vsplit of the window on a file in vim, the default positioning of the vertical window is to the left of the original window. I need to manually change it to the right with "Ctrl+w + Shift + L"

Is there any way of opening a vertical split by default to the right?

Comment: I don't think the shift is required in the moving of the window.

Comment: Also I think that ^W^R (rotate windows in column/row) beats mentally calculating the direction you want the current window to go. Also, you have less reason to check which window is current :)

Answer (score 19):

```
:set splitright
```

will do what you want. Also there is a `splitbelow` option which is for horizontal split.

Check the help

```
:help splitright
```

Comment: @timonti: Then don't forget to mark this answer as correct. You'll find the checkmark at the left of every question, below the vote count. Just click on this one.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the files in buffers already, this will work

```
:vert belowright sb N
```

where `N` is the name of the buffer